# Yii2 mailer returns an error Setting unknown property: yii\swiftmailer\Mailer::mailer

Tags: php, email, yii, yii2, swiftmailer

I have configured mailer in this way

In the component

```
'components' => [

    'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        'viewPath' => '@common/mail',

        'useFileTransport' => false,
        'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            'transport' => [
                'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
                'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
                'username' => 'gmailaccount',
                'password' => 'gmailpassword',
                'port' => '587',
                'encryption' => 'tls',
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```

In my controller i have

```
    public  function actionTestmail(){

    return \Yii::$app->mailer->compose('testmail')
        ->setFrom([Yii::$app->params['supportEmail']])  //this is set in params
        ->setTo("mysecondmail@gmail.com")
        ->setSubject('Testing yii2 mailer ')
        ->send();
}
```

The above always returns an error of setting unknown property: yii\swiftmailer\Mailer::mailer, what could be wrong,

The above configuration is a copy paste from yii2 website yet it fails to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two times repeated `mailer` in components configuration.

This is right configuration:

```
'components' => [

    'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        'viewPath' => '@common/mail',

        'useFileTransport' => false,

        'transport' => [
            'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
            'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
            'username' => 'gmailaccount',
            'password' => 'gmailpassword',
            'port' => '587',
            'encryption' => 'tls',
        ],

    ],
],
```